# fullpage.js and screen resolution

Tags: screen, resolution, fullpage.js

I use fullpage.js on my site .
Before today all design was perfect. But today "fullpage think" that my screen height = 1533. But my screen resolution 1366x768. Why this happened and how I can resolved it?

[My site must look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrLJj.png)

[Trouble with screen resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bq4vc.png)

UPD: There are trouble with screen resolution on all computers, which I show my site(( 
"Fullpage" everywhere think, that resolution bigger((

Comment: Did you update the fullpage.js version at all? 
What changes did you make since you noticed the change? Seems a problem in your side as the oficial fullpage.js website still working as expected.

Comment: I just add doctype html )))